# Fatal error:class Config not found in php?

Tags: php

I m trying to configure the class..
this is my init.php file
**init.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $GLOBALS['config'] = array(
        'mysql' => array(
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'rajaraman',
            'db' => 'sms'
        ),
    'remember' => array(
        'cookie_name' => 'hash' ,
        'cookie_expiry' => 604800
        ),
        'session' =>  array(
            'session_name' => 'user' 
        )
     );
    spl_autoload_register(function($class){
        require_once 'classes/' .$class. '.php';
    }); 
    require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
  require_once 'core/init.php';

  echo Config::get('mysql/host');
  ?>
```

**Config.php**

```
<?php
  public class Config{
    public static function get($path = null){
        if($path){
             $config = $GLOBALS['config'];
             $path = explode('/',$path);

             print_r($path);
        }
    }
  }
```

When i am trying to print the array it show me some fatal errors,i dnt what the problem actually it is please any one help me....

*Fatal error: Class 'Config' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Student Management system\index.php on line 4*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I check your code on my PC i get this error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in
>   /var/www/test/classes/Config.php on line 2

So when i removed `public` keyword before `class` it started work fine:

```
<?php
  class Config{
    public static function get($path = null){
        if($path){
             $config = $GLOBALS['config'];
             $path = explode('/',$path);

             print_r($path);
        }
    }
  }
```